# How to map Java Module Directives and Gradle configurations to declare dependencies?

Tags: gradle, java-module

I partially know the answer to this question. But there are parts in my head that are not clear!

In the Gradle documentation, they partially answered this question by exemplifying **4 directives**. But what exactly are the equivalents of the directives other than these **4 directives**? Especially, what does the "**export** **directive**" correspond to in gradle?

If I had not seen this documentation, I would have said that the "**export directive**" corresponds to the "**api**" on the gradle side. But the directive corresponding to the "**api**" is "**requires transitive**".

By the way, I took this table from the Gradle documentation.

Table: Mapping between Java module directives and Gradle configurations to declare dependencies

| Java Module Directive | Gradle Configuration | Purpose |
| --- | --- | --- |
| requires | implementation | Declaring implementation dependencies |
| requires transitive | api | Declaring API dependencies |
| requires static | compileOnly | Declaring compile only dependencies |
| requires static transitive | compileOnlyApi | Declaring compile only API dependencies |

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent of the `exports` directive in Gradle.

> The exports directive indicates which public types of the module's package are accessible to other modules.

You are not declaring a dependency with `exports`, you declare what is accessible from your module to other modules. The ability to add these restrictions was one of the major new capabilities of the module system compared to the existing classpath system.

So, if you don't declare a module, everything is exported, and if you do declare a module, then it depends on the module declaration.

Comment: Isn't that the logic of the API as well? I mean, "export" the library?

Comment: The `api` configuration is for dependencies. `export` applies to the module itself. So if you want to use the module system and `export` something, then you need to add the module-info.java in the code, there is nothing to do in gradle itself for this.